# Replaced image in Android project, but won't update in project

Tags: android, eclipse

I have an Android project, and I wanted to replace two of the images I use in it with updated ones.  So, with Eclipse closed, I replaced the two images with two of the same dimensions.  When I re-opened eclipse, it updated one of the images, but the other one is an old version of the image.  I can't figure out for the life of me how to get it to see the new one.  I have run Project->Clean , and refreshed the project, but it still references that old image for one of them.  The old image is definitely nowhere to be found in the project directory.

What am I missing here?  Keep in mind I'm not a very experienced Android dev at all.

Answer (score 8):

If you haven't found the solution yet go to menu project->clean... That should be enough.
Cheers!